# Rails Generate Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rails-generate

Everytime I attempt to use rails generate, I get the following error message. Not sure what Im doing wrong:

```
rails generate controller Say hello goodbye
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:251:in `block in default_middleware_stack': uniniti
alized constant Rails::Rack::Logger (NameError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:232:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:232:in `default_middleware_stack'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `app'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finis
her>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from E:/AptanaWorkspace/depot/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

ruby version 1.9.3
rails version 3.2.6

Comment: oops missed the controller bit but regardless the same error comes. Its from the agile web development with rails book, by Sam Ruby. Again sorry about the error.

Comment: re-run bundle to make sure all the gems are installed?

Answer (score 0):

From your log:

```
uninitialized constant Rails::Rack::Logger
```

This means something is looking for Rails::Rack:Logger but can't find it. Execute the following to see if Rack is installed.

```
bundle show rack
/home/nrowegt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rack-1.6.1
```

If nothing shows, rerun "bundle install" or "gem install rack"